# Performing a Sum or Grouped Query in SuiteScript 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Can any give a solid example of how to perform a grouped or summed query, ie "**How many sales orders has Jane Smith done this month**" in suitescript 2.0. The NetSuite Help Center examples and docs for 2.0 are so scattered and half-baked imho.

Any help would be appreciated. Below is the code im using. which returns an **UNKNOWN ERROR**. If you change search.Summary.GROUP and search.Summary.COUNT to lowercase (search.Summary.group, etc), then you get one result where the **orderCount** column actually contains the internal id, not an aggregate count

```
var results = [],
        GROUP = search.Summary.GROUP,
        COUNT = search.Summary.COUNT;

var mySalesOrderSearch = search.create({
    type: 'salesorder',
    columns: [
        "trandate",
        {
            name: 'salesrep',
            summary: GROUP
        }, {
            name: 'internalid',
            summary: COUNT
        }],
    filters: [{
        name: 'mainline',
        operator: 'is',
        values: ['T']
    }, {
        name: "trandate",
        operator: "within",
        values: ["thisyear"]
    }]
});

mySalesOrderSearch.run().each(function (result) {
    var repName = result.getText({
        "name": "salesrep",
        "summary": GROUP
    });

    var orderCount = parseInt(result.getValue({
        "name": "internalid",
        "summary": COUNT
    }), 10);

    var msg = {
        "title": "Order Count by Sales Rep",
        "details": repName + " has sold " + orderCount + " orders."
    };

    results.push(msg);
    log.debug(msg);
});

return results;
```

And here is the result when I change the summary to lowercase (search.Summary.**group**, etc)

```
{
    "error": false,
    "msg": "TESTING_POST_METHOD",
    "data": [
        {
            "title": "Order Count by Sales Rep",
            "details": "Victor Beisel has sold 524963 orders."
        }
    ]
}
```

The **524963** number in the details key is the internal id of a sales order, not the true count. And here is the result when you use the capitalized summary token (search.Summary.**GROUP**, etc) as stated by the NetSuite docs

```
{
    "error": true,
    "msg": {
        "type": "error.SuiteScriptError",
        "name": "UNEXPECTED_ERROR",
        "message": null,
        "stack": [
            "each(N/searchObject)",
            "TESTING_POST_METHOD(/SuiteScripts/XpelAffiliateOrders/XPELSS2_3PO_Index.js:159)",
            "<anonymous>(/SuiteScripts/XpelAffiliateOrders/XPELSS2_3PO_Index.js:40)",
            "post(/SuiteScripts/XpelAffiliateOrders/XPELSS2_3PO_Index.js:117)"
        ],
        "cause": {
            "type": "internal error",
            "code": "UNEXPECTED_ERROR",
            "details": null,
            "userEvent": null,
            "stackTrace": [
                "each(N/searchObject)",
                "TESTING_POST_METHOD(/SuiteScripts/XpelAffiliateOrders/XPELSS2_3PO_Index.js:159)",
                "<anonymous>(/SuiteScripts/XpelAffiliateOrders/XPELSS2_3PO_Index.js:40)",
                "post(/SuiteScripts/XpelAffiliateOrders/XPELSS2_3PO_Index.js:117)"
            ],
            "notifyOff": false
        },
        "id": "",
        "notifyOff": false
    },
    "data": null
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```js
// Assuming N/search is imported as `s`
var mySalesOrderSearch = s.create({
    type: 'salesorder'
    // Use the summary property of a Column to perform grouping/summarizing
    columns: [{
        name: 'salesrep',
        summary: s.Summary.GROUP
    },{
        name: 'internalid',
        summary: s.Summary.COUNT
    }],
    filters: [{
        name: 'mainline',
        operator: 'is',
        values: ['T']
    }]
});

mySalesOrderSearch.run().each(function (result) {
    var repId = result.getValue({
        "name": "salesrep",
        "summary": s.Summary.GROUP
    });
    var repName = result.getText({
        "name": "salesrep",
        "summary": s.Summary.GROUP
    });
    var orderCount = parseInt(result.getValue({
            "name": "internalid",
            "summary": s.Summary.COUNT
    }), 10);

    log.debug({
        "title": "Order Count by Sales Rep",
        "details": repName + " has sold " + orderCount + " orders."
    });
    return true;
});
```

Grouping specifically by month is a little more difficult as you'll need to use a formula with `TO_CHAR` on the appropriate date field to get the correct month.

Comment: The syntax is correct but it is returning 1 log only. and the orderCount variable is holding the actual internalid, not a count. The initial reason I asked this question is because we feel this may be a another bug in 2.0, for we have tried various syntax and we either get an error, or 1 result where the "count" is not correct and returns the field value instead

Comment: Also, search.Summary.GROUP and search.Summary.COUNT throw the errors mentioned above. Changing GROUP and COUNT to lowercase return the 1 result only, but no error

Comment: The code im using based off the example you gave is posted above

Comment: AFAIK when you perform a summarized search in SuiteScript, *all* columns must be grouped or summarized in some manner. Try either removing your `trandate` column, or adding a grouping/summary on it as well.

Comment: You were right by making sure all columns are of the correct summary. Also we were missing the 'return true;' on the last line of the mySalesOrderSearch.run().each body.

Comment: Ah yes, I did miss that in my example. Glad you got it worked out!